# mysql assoc error

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing this for an IT project, and I am not that experienced in using my SQL
I am trying to run a query and this is the error that I keep on getting.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function msql_fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_test\index2.php on line 8


if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

  while($query_row = msql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
```

Above is a snippet of my code I have looked for this error and I cant seem to identify it. Please help me.

Comment: Should be `mysql_fetch_assoc`. missing `y` in it.

Comment: I want `too localized` back :(

Answer (score 0):

Change from `msql_fetch_assoc()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

You have error in word "msql_fetch_assoc" :)

Must be mYsql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a function called `msql_fetch_assoc()`. You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new
> code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)
> They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation
> process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See
> the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
> Learn about [prepared
> statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead,
> and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or
> [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this
> [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will
> help you decide which.